# About Servlet binding patterns and default servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, undertow

I have a Servlet I want to bind to `"/"` pattern. After that, all works fine for all URLs including application root but I also need the `default` servlet for static files support.

After I add it into web.xml this way I got `404` error at the application root URL, but all other URLs are still successfully handled by the Servlet assigned to `"/"`.

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
<servlet-mapping>
```

After I bind the Servlet also to `""` pattern it works fine. How I understand this pattern is related to the root URL of the application.

Could you help me to find out the reasons for such behavior?

P.S. I check the behavior with TomCat and Undertow.

Comment: Don't think that's a copy. Here is about why the `*.html` binding pattern for one servlet is affecting the handling of `/` binding pattern of another servlet. How I know the `*.html` like patterns are the last in the checklist of servlet container patterns. Much more strange because of that.

Comment: @Selaron, my question is not about meaning of any binding pattern. I know what mean `"" `, `"/" ` or `".*`. I'm asking about why the behaviour of `"/"` is a bit different after I add binding of default Servlet to `*. `. If I have only `/` binding also application root URL is handled OK. But after I add binding of default Servlet to `*. ` the behaviour changes and I need the additional trick to bind the root Servlet back.

Comment: I retracted the duplicate close vote and suppose these comments can be deleted as I got your question wrong initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your issue using Apache Tomcat 9.0.21 and following servlet:

```
package my.sample;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().write("servlet1: " + req.getServletPath());
    }
}
```

And web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="myApp" version="4.0">
    <display-name>myWebApp</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.sample.Servlet1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Opening the URL `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/` results in error 404 as described by you. Other URLs not matching any `default` servlet `url-pattern` are handled by my `servlet1` and produce output like `servlet1: /hello` for example when opening `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/hello`

When removing the `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` from `default` servlet mapping, your issue is gone and I get `servlet1: /` as response when opening `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/`.

When adding the `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` to `servlet1` servlet mapping I get `servlet1: /index.html` as response when opening `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/`.

This suggests the reason for your issue is that path `/` is internally forwarded to the welcome-file index.html which perfectly matches the *.html url-pattern configured for the `default` servlet in your case - and thus the `default` servlet is chosen to handle the `/` request path. If an index.html is abscent, the `default` servlet sends the 404 error observed by you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! All is much simpler comparing to the my expectations))